# Setting different From address for mail send through Office 365

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, sendmail, system.net.mail

While sending mail using office 365 how can we set different from address. Basically the credentials I am giving are for office 365 account/username and from email address I am mentioning the different account. So this has to be same?

Below is my code.

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("toid@domain.com", "To Name"));
msg.From = new MailAddress("fromid@domain.com", "From Name");
msg.Subject = "Azure Web App Email using smtp.office365.com";
msg.Body = "Test message using smtp.office365.com on Azure from a Web App";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("o365id@domain.com", "O365 PASS");
client.Port = 587;
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

But it is giving me below error,

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does
>   not have permissions to send as this sender

Basically I want to set the different from address while sending the mail.

**EDIT 1** : The from email address will be the logged in users email id. This will be from same domain, but can we give the send as permission for common mailbox considering this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error mean the credentials your trying to send with doesn't have the SendAS permission for the user/mailbox your trying to send as the Sender. To fix that you will either need to grant that through the Portal https://technet.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/jj919240%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 or using PowerShell

```
Add-ADPermission -Identity helpdesksupport -User o365id@domain.com -ExtendedRights "Send As"
```

Comment: So this is you are telling about email id which is provided in NetworkCredentials i.e. o365id@domain.com for which SendAs Permission need to be given and NOT for the From email adress ? I can send the mail if I provide the same email address in network credentials and from email address

Comment: SendAS permissions (as the name should imply) means that the user your granting the permission to has rights to "SendAS" the user/emailAddress owner that your granting the rights to.  So o365id@domain.com would be granted rights to SendAS helpdesksupport in the example I've given above

Comment: helpdesksupport is username/emailid ? Also how can i grant the "SendAs" permission to email address ? Is this applicable to multiple users ?

Comment: I have edited my question, so basically from address should be the logged in users is this possible ?

Comment: You don't grant rights to an Email Address the Email address is a property of an Object in Active Directory maybe a Mailbox, Mail Enabled Public Folder, Mail user. Whatever credentials is trying to sendAS that AD object needs to be granted the SendAS permission. The credentials that you use needs to be a valid Office365 Credential sounds like you might be talking about hybrid Authentication which I'm not sure will work with SMTP.  I would suggest you put some detail around how you tenant is configured hybrid etc.

Comment: Got your point.. basically our requirement is whoever the user is logging into the application, his email id can be added in from email address ?